# How do I add text on inline circles?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I have 5 circles placed like this

[image]

I want to add a small "caption" under each circle like this

[image]

For the circles I am using the `v-avatar` component in Vuetify, but I don't really know how to add the captions in a way that it looks like the previous image. This is the code I have for now:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.dark-grey-text {
    color: #707070 !important;
}

.pf-text{
    font-family: 'Alata', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<v-app>
  <v-container>
    <h3 class="dark-grey-text pf-text text-center mt-2">INTENSITY</h3>
      <v-row class="mx-2 mt-2">
        <div class="mx-auto">
          <v-avatar color="#877787" size="25"></v-avatar>
          <v-avatar color="#B28C81" class="ml-4" size="25"></v-avatar>
          <v-avatar color="#E5DB9C" class="ml-4" size="25"></v-avatar>
          <v-avatar color="#CE7E7E" class="ml-4" size="25"></v-avatar>
          <v-avatar color="#707070" class="ml-4" size="25"></v-avatar>
        </div>
      </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the `<v-avatar/>` to a div that has a flex column. Then apply `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row` to the div that's wrapping them.

```html
<v-row ...>

  <div class="mx-auto d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center">
      <v-avatar color="#877787" size="25"/>
      <span class="caption grey--text">P</span>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center ml-4">
      <v-avatar color="#B28C81" size="25"/>
      <span class="caption grey--text">edP</span>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center ml-4">
      <v-avatar color="#E5DB9C" size="25"/>
      <span class="caption grey--text">edT</span>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center ml-4">
      <v-avatar color="#CE7E7E" size="25"/>
      <span class="caption grey--text">edC</span>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center ml-4">
      <v-avatar color="#707070" size="25"/>
      <span class="caption grey--text">EdS</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</v-row>
```

[image]

Here is a code [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-perlman-8xsk3?file=/src/components/Playground.vue).